# Issue with delete column and insert data into excel file

Tags: excel, phpexcel, setvalue

I checked a lot of topics on stack's about my issue, but every resolution don't work for me.

So please help me with two things.

1) I want to delete column 'M'.
I checked `$excelObj->getActiveSheet()->removeColumn('M');` (Doesn't work)

2) I have got a bit of code:

```
//ISP MCR FULLAUTOMAT
for ($row = 1;$row <= $lastrow; $row++) {
    if(strpos(($worksheet->getCell('K'.$row)->getValue()), $orion_automat) !== false) {
        if((strpos(($worksheet->getCell('J'.$row)->getValue()), $mcr_isp_full) !== false) and 
            (strpos(($worksheet->getCell('J'.$row)->getValue()), $mcr_isp_full_anal) == false)) {
            $full++;
        }
    }
}
```

After the `$full++;` I want to make something like that:
If script will add +1 to `$full`, he will also write `1` in the column "N" in a `$row`.

I tried this:

```
$excelObj->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('N'.$row, '1');
```

And this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow('N', $row, '1');
```

If someone has got a little bit time to help, please write what I can try more.
Thank you.

---

Yours faithfully - Mariusz Adamczewski

Comment: `1) I want to delete column 'M'. I checked $excelObj->getActiveSheet()->removeColumn('M');` You say it "Doesn't work".... explain what you mean, what did you expect?.... I've just tested it, and it works exactly as expected when I tested it a moment ago.... it removes all data from column M, then adjusts N to become M, O to become N, etc adjusting all formulae accordingly

Comment: `2) I tried this:

$excelObj->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('N'.$row, '1');` And what happened?

Comment: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow('N', $row, '1')` This method requires a numeric reference for the column, not a letter